# Can't Connect to Database when Web Application is deployed to IIS

Tags: iis-5

i have developed an application and it is working fine but when ever i create a virtual directory for it in IIS and run the application i am getting connection failure exception and named pipes exception.

thanks!

Comment: the connection string i am using is 
<add name="CONTACTINFOConnectionString" connectionString="Database=CONTACTINFO;Server=localhost;Integrated Security=True"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> from web.config
when ever i run the applicaiton as view in browser it is working fine.but when i add it to iis and run the application using my ip instead of loacl host iam getting the following error:
Cannot open database "CONTACTINFO" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'SQLSERVERNAME\ASPNET'.

Answer (score 2):

Without any code or details of the language it is hard to guess what the issue can be however a common one that occurs with asp.net could be your database connection string.  Are you using a SQl Server / Sql Server Express database with your application? You need to check that the connection string.

The problem is the Integrated Security=True setting in your connection string.  IIS uses the ASPNET windows login which will be different to the Windows login used when running from VS.  You've got a few options:

1. Grant the ASPNET user the required access rights on your database
2. Use Sql Server authentication:  Set up a user on the database as a sql login and pass this username / password in on the connection string and set Integrated Security=False
3. Change the identity IIS runs under to one that has access to the DB.

There may be other options also however I think these are most common.  Which to choose depends on the architecture you are deploying to, personally I almost always go for Sql Server Authentication using a username and password.  The web.config can be encrypted for further security if required.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you having some issue with the database connection from your application. Can you post your code and the exact nature of the error.